# How can a same system call accept different paramters in UNIX?

Tags: c, unix, overloading, system-calls

Since Unix is written in C, there is no concept of function overloading. But still Unix System calls can be invoked with different paramteters.

Example:

```
open(fd, flag);
open(fd, flag, mode);
```

How is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is likely to use variable length arguments.

For example.

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

It uses variable arguments.

From `/usr/include/fcntl.h` on Red Hat Linux 5:

```
extern int open (__const char *__file, int __oflag, ...) __nonnull ((1));
```

Here's an example of how this might work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int my_open(const char *file, int flag, ...)
{
    va_list va;

    if ((flag & O_CREAT) != 0) {
        va_start(va, flag);
        int mode = va_arg(va, int);
        va_end(va);
        printf("file=%s, flag=%d, mode=%o\n", file, flag, mode);
    } else {
        printf("file=%s, flag=%d\n", file, flag);
    }
}

int main()
{
    my_open("filename1", O_RDONLY);
    my_open("filename2", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
}
```

Output:

```
file=filename1, flag=0
file=filename2, flag=65, mode=644
```

Answer (score -1):

Because it was written before C89 standardization, where the compiler did not check arguments for correctness. Functions were declared like this

```
myfunc(a, b, c, d)
char *b;
int *c;
{

}
```

which is equivalent to today's

```
int myfunc(int a, char *b, int *c, int d)
{

}
```